# Jackson on Android: NoClassDefFoundError ObjectMapper error

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, noclassdeffounderror

I've tried to implement Robospice into my application according the Robospice's [Starter Guide](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/wiki/Starter-Guide). 
I'm getting the following errors:

> 09-11 20:28:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(25480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 09-11 20:28:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(25480):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
>
> 09-11 20:28:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(25480):  at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:54)
>
> 09-11 20:28:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(25480):  at
>   com.my.app.io.service.JsonSpiceService.createRestTemplate(JsonSpiceService.java:37)

Here is what I've tried so far:

- I have the following jars included (`libs` folder): jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar, jackson-core-2.2.2.jar, jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar (among all the other Robospice-related jars but Jackson is the one causing problems). I've also tested it with 2.2.3 (same problem)
- All of them are checked under 'Order and Export' in Eclipse (as well as all of the other Robospice-related jars)
- I'm not using Maven
- I've tried deleting and adding new jars, cleaning the project - none of these worked
- My app is targeted at API level 17 (Google APIs, 4.2.2)

What else could cause this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are referencing `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` when you should be referencing `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` which is in `jackson-databind`.

This is probably because `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` uses the old version, which is in `jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.xx`. You can get those [here](http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/).

Otherwise, use `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` **(note the 2)** which correctly uses the newest version of `jackson`.

Comment: Thanks! This solution helped me - i was looking at an old tutorial and they used MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter instead of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and brainless me just copied and pasted.